# What is the correct way to upload Pandas to a SQL Server table?

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

I read a csv file into Pandas,
did some manipulations (mainly- filtered the rows and the columns),
and want to upload it into a table in SQL server.

There are some examples how to do it row by row, but this is very inefficient. Is there a way to do it in one chunk? in several chunks?

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-sql

Comment: Have you seen [to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) documentation?